# How to make a variable icon of Android application?

Tags: android

Usually the icon is fixed. But I want to make an application: when user presses the icon, it won't open any new UI but just change the icon itself. That means it has only two status and can be changed by users pressing on it.

Are some code examples available for this?

As you can see from below screenshots of my phone. The app icon represents a cleaner. When I press it, the 2nd picture shows that the icon changes and it won't enter any UI, just shows the percent of phone's processes cleaning status.
I want to make an app with this effect.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What "icon" are you referring to?

Comment: The icon on Android desktop, like twitter, facebook, Pocket...

Comment: It is a [widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: You can not change the app's icon. It is pre-bundled with the apk. A workaround and a possible overkill is to create a separate home screen launcher for your app (essentially, a new home screen).

Comment: Hi, could you please check my main post? I give an example to show what I want and how others have done. @ColorWP.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change your application icon at runtime, in terms of what is displayed by the home screen in its launcher.

You are welcome to write a [home screen app widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) that can respond to user input and can change its UI.

Comment: Hi, could you please check my main post? I give an example to show what I want and how others have done.

Comment: @TomXue: That's not an app widget, but a floating window located where the icon's shortcut is. You can even see the icon's caption at the bottom. Personally, I seriously dislike such techniques.